# .PY to .EXE looks runs slightly different on different computers

Tags: python, tkinter, exe

I have converted my .PY file to an .EXE using auto-py-to-exe.  It works fine and runs great on my computer.  When I transfer it to another it runs and works fine but looks slightly different, it is affecting the usability slightly.  This is a Python program mainly using Tkinter.  The issue is some of the 'text' boxes are in the wrong spot and overlap buttons.  The text boxes are 1 row up and out of place, but only on some other computers.

Comment: probably a font configuration difference. tkinter relies on the system to display the default font

Comment: Do you use `place` to arrange your widgets? If you're using that, and calculating exact locations for widgets, that can cause problems on different systems due to differences in fonts, resolutions, etc.

Comment: I am using .grid(row,column) for most of what I do.  Using .pack() on certain windows.  When it comes to fonts, I left it on the default, I haven't gotten around to changing it yet.  Also using .grid() shouldn't be an entire row off because of fonts... as far as I know.